# What is the difference between InputBox () and Application.InputBox()?

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

When I write this sub:

```
Sub IB()
result = Application.InputBox("type a number", , , , , , , 1)
End Sub
```

The method InputBox has "type" as its last optional parameter, which allows you to restrict the datatype a user can insert. I set it to "1" in this example, restricting the datatype to "number". As far as I understand, by writing it like Application.InputBox I make explicit that InputBox is a method applied to the application. But when I remove the object "application" in the next sub:

```
Sub IB2()
result = InputBox("type a number", , , , , , ,)
End Sub
```

InputBox no longer has the paramater "type" as an option . I'd like to know why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox):

> The InputBox method differs from the InputBox function in that it
> allows selective validation of the user's input, and it can be used
> with Excel objects, error values, and formulas. Notice that
> Application.InputBox calls the InputBox method; InputBox with no
> object qualifier calls the InputBox function.